# Is there another way to fix this problem?

Tags: java, selenium, file, webdriver, bufferedreader

Is there any problem in code? cause // click number 2
is not working with me ( number 1 working fine why number 2 is not ) !!!

```
@Test
public void maintenance() {
    
    String file = "R:\\hellthinky\\resources\\file.txt";
    
    try {
        
         BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String lineText = null;
         
         while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
             
             driver.navigate().to(lineText);
             
             WebElement button = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
                        (By.className("btn-main")));
                        button.click();
             
             WebElement link = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 40))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
                        (By.className("btn-main")));
                        link.click(); // click number 2
             
             WebElement body = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
                        .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
                        (By.tagName("body")));
                        body.getText();
             
         }
         
         lineReader.close();
         
    } 
    
    catch (IOException error) {
        
        System.out.println(error);
        
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: You don't need `WebDriverWait` if you use `driver.get(lineText)`. You can lose all that unneeded code and just get a reference to the `WebElement` object directly. That will greatly simplify your code. Does `bin-main` refer to the same element in both cases? If not, you are only clicking the first element. You need to operate on the collection if more than one element has the same class.

Answer (score 0):

In case after the first click on the button something occurs on the page you first have to validate that action happened (like some element appeared etc) and only after that to wait until the button becomes clickable again.
Otherwise you are checking it clickability immediately after clicking on it while the button itself possibly still was not changed / updated so clicking on it again will have no effect or something else.